# HttpPost to different Website in Controller Action Mehod

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I need to post data to http://differentdomain:8080/ipg/servlet_pay and redirect there.How do I http post request to different website from controller

```
public IActionResult PaymentOption(PaymentOptionVM paymentOption)
{
            var option = paymentOption.opPaymentMethod;
            if (option.Equals("ib")
            {
                 return Redirect("http://differentdomain:8080/ipg/servlet_pay?encdata=" + paymentOption.encData);
            }
 }
```

Comment: From the server side, you can post data there _or_ you can tell the browser to redirect there , but not both. (A redirect is always a GET operation, never a POST, and it's only done from the browser - the server just tells the browser what to request next). Maybe this payment gateway has preferred way that you are supposed to integrate with it, because what you're suggesting at the moment doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks. I had to do it from front end